# xpath: extract text following <br> doesn't work

Tags: xpath

**My HTML:**

```
<strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Prices and Rentals</span></strong>
<br>
<br>
“ Prices of …”
<br>
<br>
```

I want to extract the text after "Prices and Rentals" --> br --> br

**Desired Extracted Text:**

“ Prices of …”

**My xpath selector:**

(//strong/span[contains(text(), "Prices and Rentals")])[1]/br/br//text()

It can't seems to detect the "br". Thank you

Comment: In HTML and XHTML, the `br` element is empty, so you can neither nest them nor put text into them, therefore none of `br/br//text()` makes sense. As for the input snippet, how is that parsed, as text/html with an HTML parser?

Answer (score 4):

`//strong[span[contains(., 'Prices and Rentals')]]/following-sibling::br[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]` would give a text node containing

```
“ Prices of …”
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But It doesn't work. br is the sibling of strong and NOT span.

Comment: @123456, right, I adjusted the path expression.

Comment: @123456 in case this answer worked you should accept and upvote it. Otherwise you should let us know it is still not helped.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: Pls see my answer. There is no need for sibling for the br

Comment: @123456 your XPath is just a slightly modified version of Martin's XPath. IMHO no noticeable improvements

Answer (score 0):

```
//strong//following-sibling::br[text()]
```

Comment: Please post some comments to your code as well. Also note that `br` (single line-break) tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag and so no children.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one, admittedly convoluted, but doesn't depend on positioning:

```
//*[.//span[contains(., 'Prices and Rentals')]]//text()[not(parent::*/name()="span")][string-length(normalize-space())>0]
```

Comment: Using just `[normalize-space()]` predicate instead of `[string-length(normalize-space())>0]` should be enough

Comment: @JaSON Maybe it should, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

A workable answer is

```
//strong/span[contains(text(), 'Prices and Rentals')]/following::br[2]/following-sibling::text()
```